# Set containing directory permissions using setfacl?

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a file e.g script.php in the following folder structure style /home/site/admin/script.php

I have used setfacl to allow a new user that logs in remotely permission to include that file in another script that is being executed (remotely).

However this only works if all the containing folders have Others set to execute.
Firstly is that even a problem, I have been told directories can have Others set to execute with no problems but this is including my home folder which seems a bit open to me.

So I'm guessing I can use setfacl to give the user execute permissions on all the parent directories, but is would I have to do this individually or is there a command that might traverse upwards?

I am only just starting to undertsand permissions in general so apologies if I have got some things wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For directories, execute permission allows users to traverse the directory, down to lower levels of the directory tree.  Whether that's acceptable from a security point of view depends on whether you want to allow people to use those directories.  But if you want people to be able to access /home/site/admin/script.php, they are going to have to traverse /home, /home/site, and /home/site/admin to do it - there's no way around it.

Note though that that doesn't necessarily allow them to list the contents of those directories; the `r` permission is for that.  `x` just allows them to read and/or write the files within the directories.

If you don't want to allow users to traverse your home directory, then you should move the site files to a public location.  /var/www or /srv/www are standard.

No, there's no command to traverse upwards as far as I know.  All you have to do is run `chmod a+x /home /home/site /home/site/admin`, one time.

Comment: Ok so I never really need Others to be able to read or write a directory only execute, assuming they need to read a file within that directory?

Comment: Can you maybe clear this up as well, it appears that to run a php script only read permissions are required not execute is that right? So if I want to stop Others running the php script I need Others set to not read and my logged in user to be given read permissions?

Comment: Sorry last one I hope, it seems using ACL permissions these are equivalent to a Group setting. When I turn off all the Group privileges my logged in user can't run the script, but with Group r it can.

Comment: Yes, you only need the x permission for Other on directories, not r or w.  Yes, php only needs r, not x.  And yes, ACL permissions are like groups, except that there can be only one group, but any number of ACLs.

Comment: I'm finding that permissions of 770 i.e Others not getting any permissions for a folder is still allowing apache to server files in that folder, is that normal or have I somehow made Apache a group owner of that folder?

Comment: It turns out I have made apache the group owner.